# How to count the consecutive characters in a string

Tags: vb.net, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I dont have any idea on what to do.
Here is the scenario. I need to count how many deletions to make so that the string dont have any consecutive characters in it. For example

AAABBBCCC = 6 deletions. 2 on c, 2 on b, and 2 on a to make it no consecutive.

Thanks for any help. Im am writing in VB.Net.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what should the result be ("ABC" or the count of each letter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method should work for any type:

```
Shared Function CountConsecutiveDuplicates(Of T)(input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Int32
    Dim count As Int32 = 0
    Dim comparer = EqualityComparer(Of T).Default

    ' optimization for lists and arrays: '
    Dim listT = TryCast(input, IList(Of T))
    If listT IsNot Nothing Then
        If listT.Count <= 1 Then Return 0
        For i As Int32 = 0 To listT.Count - 2
            If comparer.Equals(listT(i), listT(i + 1)) Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        Return count
    End If

    If Not input.Any() Then Return 0
    Dim this As T = input.First()
    For Each item As T In input.Skip(1)
        If comparer.Equals(this, item) Then
            count += 1
        End If
        this = item
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim numDeletes = CountConsecutiveDuplicates("AAABBBCCC") '  6
```

You could make it an extension method:

```
Module GeneralExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Function CountConsecutiveDuplicates(Of T)(input As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Int32
        Dim count As Int32 = 0
        Dim comparer = EqualityComparer(Of T).Default

        ' optimization for lists and arrays: '
        Dim listT = TryCast(input, IList(Of T))
        If listT IsNot Nothing Then
            If listT.Count <= 1 Then Return 0
            For i As Int32 = 0 To listT.Count - 2
                If comparer.Equals(listT(i), listT(i + 1)) Then
                    count += 1
                End If
            Next
            Return count
        End If

        If Not input.Any() Then Return 0
        Dim this As T = input.First()
        For Each item As T In input.Skip(1)
            If comparer.Equals(this, item) Then
                count += 1
            End If
            this = item
        Next
        Return count
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can even use it in this way:

```
Dim numDeletes = "AAABBBCCC".CountConsecutiveDuplicates()
```

Comment: can you make it by characters? example is 
AAABBBCCC
AABBCC
AAAABBBCC

output
6
3
6

Comment: @MixAustria: yes, then you have to split it first: `String.Join(" ", "AAABBBCCC AABBCC AAAABBBCC".Split().Select(Function(s) s.CountConsecutiveDuplicates()))` yields your desired output `6 3 6`.

Comment: im in a for loop where i need to check for every line of my multiline textbox. but it only returns 1 result.

For x As Integer = 1 To count
                    If inputArr(x).Length - 1 >= 1 And inputArr(x).Length - 1 <= 10 Then
                        Dim numDeletes = CountConsecutiveDuplicates(inputArr(x - 1))
                        txtResult.Text = numDeletes
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Hell no!")
                    End If
                Next x

Comment: @MixAustria: but you are using a single TextBox, how do you want to show the result for every line if you always overwrite it with  `txtResult.Text = numDeletes`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Module Tester

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim _inStr As String = "AAABBBBCCCCC"
        Dim _reduced As Char() = _inStr.ToCharArray.Distinct().ToArray

        Console.WriteLine("{0} >> {1}", _inStr, New String(_reduced))

        For Each _c As Char In _reduced
            Console.WriteLine("Char: {0} remove: {1}", _c, _inStr.Where(Function(x) x = _c).Count - 1)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

```
AAABBBBCCCCC >> ABC
Char: A remove: 2
Char: B remove: 3
Char: C remove: 4
```

Comment: can you make the console.writeline to display the output in a multiline textbox. that would be very much appreciated

Comment: Try it on your own first, it's not really hard. If you have a problem with that you can always ask  a new question. good luck

Comment: But this does not count consecutive characters. This doesn't contain consecutive duplicates: `ABA`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you want to count the deletions to make or what you intend to do with the result but a short sweet solution to simply removing all consecutive characters could look like this:

```
Dim str as String = "AAABBBCCC"
For Each ch As Char In str
    str = str.Replace(ch, "")
    str = str & ch
Next
```

This will simply return "ABC". You could always add some variables and/or outputs for counting the removal of each character if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somthing like that,

```
    Dim myString As String = "AAAABBCCCDDDDD"
    Dim toDelete As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
    Dim intLoopIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To myString.Length - 1

        Do While myString(i).ToString = myString(i + 1).ToString
            toDelete.Add(i + 1)
        Loop
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("You must delelte in total : " & toDelete.Count.ToString & " character(s)")

    For k = 0 To toDelete.Count - 1
        Debug.Write("Must delete the character from your string at position : " & toDelete(k).ToString)
    Next
```

try it ! and play with :)